# PDF.js Inserting Images

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I've started using [PDF.js](https://github.com/Marak/pdf.js/), an excelent work, by the way.

But now I want to insert an image (from a canvas element) on the pdf page. Here's my code:

```
var image = myCanvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0,0,400,300),
doc = new pdf();
doc.setProperties({
    title: fileName,
    author: 'VirtuaLab®',
    creator: 'pdf.js'
});
doc.addPage();
data = doc.output();
```

But I haven't found anything about inserting images on PDF.js pages.

Maybe `doc.image()` or `doc.addImage`?

Comment: The most common use case is inserting an image as stamp annotation via a custom appearance stream, that way you don't need to edit the actual pdf page contents. Here's more about that: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/what-are-appearance-streams/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for [Bytescout](http://bytescout.com)

Unfortunately PDF.js not working with images and that is why we developed [PDF Generator SDK for Javascript](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/index.html) (free for non-commercial use) where you can add image (from url or canvas) like this:

```
// load image from local file
pdf.imageLoadFromUrl('image1.jpg');
// place this mage at given X, Y coordinates on the page
pdf.imagePlace(20, 40);
```

Important to say that you can face limitation on image size as BytescoutPDF.js may consumes memory to process large image (this issue is caused by the memory limitations for javascript).

However the script should work fine in case you just need to insert logo image or small picture into generated pdf.

**UPDATE**: the latest version of [jsPDF](http://jspdf.com/) (not to be confused with PDF.js) seems to work with images, see the sample on [examples page](http://jspdf.com/).

Comment: Hello @Eugene Can we add html(or div) with images to generate pdf? I thi is possible plaese share some code example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PlanetHackers in bytescout simple html formating is supported for text and links but not for images, unfortunately. images can be placed using .imagePlace() method

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to use an `<img>` instead of a `<canvas>` with pdf.js.

So here is my fix for this problem, insert the returned image in a canvas as normal, give the canvas a `display: none;`.

Then use the `.toDataURL()` method of the canvas element to get a `src` for your img.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanves");
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

this here working.
pdf.js and html2canvas

[codepen](https://codepen.io/manhldvxut/pen/NWBWKob?editors=1010)

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
function generatePdf(){
var doc = new jsPDF();

// Source HTMLElement or a string containing HTML.
var elementHTML = document.querySelector("#content");

doc.html(elementHTML, {
    callback: function(doc) {
        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('document-html.pdf');
    },
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    autoPaging: 'text',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 190, // Target width in the PDF document
    windowWidth: 675 // Window width in CSS pixels
});
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.